# Create Shipping cost and Deliery Date field in Woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to know how I can create two new fields from PHP in WordPress/WooCommerce. The fields should be added to the checkout and one should be for Shipping Cost and the other for Delivery Day. These should be received in the purchase order from the admin side. Initially, I need them to be open text fields that can be seen from the WooCommerce checkout on the front-end.

If you need more information, I need this to understand how to send these fields, as I am implementing a JS module to create a shipping cost calculator, which also allows me to send the delivery day. For example:

Buenos Aires >>
Shipping cost: 500
Delivery day: Monday

New York >>
Shipping cost: 1000
Delivery day: Tuesday

I tried to do it by adding a WooCommerce filter, registering the field, and adding it to the purchase order column. But none of that worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code and add your JS Module to create the shipping cost calculator.

```
/**
 * Add custom field to the checkout page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', function ( $checkout ) {
    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __( 'Order Meta' ) . '</h2>';
    woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_shipping_cost',
        array(
            'type'  => 'number',
            'required'  => true,
            'label' => __( 'Custom Shipping Cost' ),
        ),
        $checkout->get_value( 'custom_shipping_cost' )
    );
    woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_shipping_date',
        array(
            'type'  => 'date',
            'required'  => true,
            'label' => __( 'Custom Shipping Date' ),
        ),
        $checkout->get_value( 'custom_shipping_date' )
    );
    echo '</div>';
} );

/**
 * Checkout Process
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'customised_checkout_field_process' );
function customised_checkout_field_process() {
    if ( ! $_POST['custom_shipping_cost'] ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter cost!' ), 'error' );
    }
    
    if ( ! $_POST['custom_shipping_date'] ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter date!' ), 'error' );
    }
}

/**
 * Update the value given in custom field
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['custom_shipping_cost'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'custom_shipping_cost', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_shipping_cost'] ) );
    }
    
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['custom_shipping_date'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'custom_shipping_date', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_shipping_date'] ) );
    }
}
```